# Ray Tracing: Only use single ray instead of both reflection & refraction rays

Tags: c++, c, trace, raytracing

I am currently trying to understand the ray tracer developed by Kevin Beason (smallpt: http://www.kevinbeason.com/smallpt/) and if I understand the code correctly he randomly chooses to either reflect or refract the ray (if the surface is both reflective and refractive).

Line 71-73:

```
return obj.e + f.mult(depth>2 ? (erand48(Xi)<P ?   // Russian roulette
radiance(reflRay,depth,Xi)*RP:radiance(Ray(x,tdir),depth,Xi)*TP) :
radiance(reflRay,depth,Xi)*Re+radiance(Ray(x,tdir),depth,Xi)*Tr);
```

Can anybody please explain the disadvantages of only casting a single ray instead of both of them? I had never heard of this technique and I am curious what the trade-off is, given that it results in a huge complexity reduction.

Comment: Have you looked at [this presentation](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8g97JkuSSBwUENiWTJXeGtTOHFmSm51UC01YWtCZw) that explains everything and is clearly linked to on that site?

Comment: Yes, I have read the presentation and it is great! What I am looking for is a more in depth explanation on how only casting a single ray affects the algorithm's efficiency. Why did he decide that for depths up to 2 both rays should be evaluated but not afterwards (i.e. is there any reasoning behind why it is exactly 2 or is it more or less random?).

Comment: more or less random, but the idea probably is that you will get most color intensity from your first few reflections and absorptions. The further you reflect/refract, the more insignificant contributions should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a monte-carlo ray tracer. Its advantages are that you don't spawn an exponentially increasing number of rays - which can occur in some simple geometries.. The down side is that you need to average over a large number of samples. Typically you sample until the expected deviation from the true value is "low enough". Working out how many samples is required requires some stats - or you just take a lot of samples.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably he's relying on super-sampling pixels and trusting that the average colour will work out roughly correct, although not as accurate.

i.e. fire 4 rays through one pixel and on average 2 are reflected, 2 are refracted.
Combine them to get an approximation of one ray reflected and refracted.

Comment: From looking at the code this looks about right see (comments on) lines 83, 84.